# Android:Want to add some extra hours and minutes from selected for setting the alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-timepicker

I want to add some extra hours and minutes from the selected for e.g.If I am selected an time 11.30 PM so extra 5.30 will be added so the alarm will set at 4.30.

How can we do this?

Below are some code to refer:-

```
public class AndroidTimeActivity extends Activity {

     TimePicker myTimePicker;
     Button buttonstartSetDialog;
     Button buttonCancelAlarm;
     TextView textAlarmPrompt;

     TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

     final static int RQS_1 = 1;

     public static final long HOUR = 3600*1000; 

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            textAlarmPrompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);

            buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
            buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
        openTimePickerDialog(false);

       }});

            buttonCancelAlarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            buttonCancelAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
        cancelAlarm();
       }});

        }

     private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

      timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
        AndroidTimeActivity.this, 
        onTimeSetListener, 
        calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
        calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
        is24r);
      timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");  

      timePickerDialog.show();

     }

        OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener
        = new OnTimeSetListener(){

      @Override
      public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

       Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
       Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

       calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
       calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
       calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
       calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

       if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
        //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
        calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
       }

       setAlarm(calSet);
      }};

     private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

      textAlarmPrompt.setText(
        "\n\n***\n"
        + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
        + "***\n");

       System.out.println("Time is minutes:"+targetCal.getTime());

       //DateFormat newDate = new DateFormat(targetCal.getTime() + 2 * HOUR);

      Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

     }

     private void cancelAlarm(){

      textAlarmPrompt.setText(
        "\n\n***\n"
        + "Alarm Cancelled! \n"
        + "***\n");

      Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

     }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Increase the values when you are about to set the time for the alarm.

```
       calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay + <increasedHours>);
       calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute + <increasedMinutes>);
       calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
       calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Now to display it to the user :

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){
     if(targetCal.get(Calendar.HOUR) > 12) 
          hours = targetCal.get(Calendar.HOUR) -12;
     else
          hours = targetCal.get(Calendar.HOUR);

    textAlarmPrompt.setText(
        "\n\n***\n"
        + "Alarm is set@ " + hours +  " : " + targetCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+ "\n"
        + "***\n");

    // rest of your logic
     }
```

Comment: If i add the 5.00 in 11.30 it will get the 16.30 and i want it will set to 4.30 PM.

Comment: Yes..but we need to show to the user also so thats why we want that.:)

Comment: Okay, cool! I am sure you would already have a logic written for AM/PM. If not, all you need to do is take the hour value, check if it's greater than 12 or not. If hoursValue>12, then it's PM and hoursValue = hoursValue -12. Should do the job. :D

Comment: Not getting can you please edit the above so we know it very well.

Comment: updated my answer. You should be able to understand it better now. :)